# Install programs without installers like Eclipse

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, eclipse

I have just downloaded `eclipse` for php dev's and after extracting it from the archive I discovered that it has no installer since I'm guessing that `~/Downloads/` is not where Programmes potentially shared by all users are supposed to end up. Is it good practice to `mv` the whole folder into `/usr/share/Eclipse/` and symlink it's executable in `/usr/share/applications` so Ubuntu realizes that Eclipse is installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no such "good practice". Look at the unpacked files and see if there's a `README` or `INSTALL` file containing installation instructions for this particular product. These instructions won't work for other software packages. The only "good practice" I can suggest is to read ALL the text files in the unpacked directory (use `file *` to check).